# Display Table data from 3 sql tables and display with a php condition - Using full join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm new to PHP, so please bear with me. I am working on a database project at work, where I'm interning.
I'm trying to display a table given that the data has been fetched from the database. I have 3 tables

Table vege_plant

- uuid
- name

Table vege_location

- uuid
- location

Table vege_data

- uuid
- vege_plants_uuid
- vege_location_uuid
- transect_num
- quadrant_num
- alive
- dead

My PHP code looks like this:

```
<?php

       $sql = mysql_query('SELECT vege_data.*, vege_location.*, vege_plants.*
       FROM vege_data
       JOIN vege_location ON vege_location.uuid =vege_data.vege_location_uuid
       JOIN vege_plants ON vege_plants.uuid = vege_data.vege_plants_uuid;);
            echo '<table class = "table table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Transect Number</th>
        <th>Quadrat Number</th>
        <th>Plant Name</th>
        <th>Alive</th>
        <th>Dead</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>';
            $count = 1;    

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td contenteditable="true">';
            echo '<td>';
            echo $row['location'];
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td contenteditable="true">';
            echo $row['transect_num'];
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td contenteditable="true">';
            echo $row['quadrant_num'];
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td contenteditable="true">';
            echo $row['name'];
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td contenteditable="true">';
            echo $row['alive'];
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td>';
            echo $row['dead'];
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
```

However, it's failing to display, not alerting any errors. I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: I dont know if its typing mistake or you did it on you app too you are missing single qoute at 1st statement $sql=..... at the  end near closing );

And if not try mysql_fetch_array instead of assco

Comment: Thanx a lot. Spent an hour not noticing this. :( :D

Comment: If you find answer  helpful  then Please Accept @shakela Tamuti

Answer (score 0):

Try This there is a syntax error at line 1st single qoute missing

```
   $sql = mysql_query('SELECT vege_data.*, vege_location.*, vege_plants.*
   FROM vege_data
   JOIN vege_location ON vege_location.uuid =vege_data.vege_location_uuid
   JOIN vege_plants ON vege_plants.uuid = vege_data.vege_plants_uuid;');


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```